# delete post meta by AJAX

Tags: jquery, metabox, ajax, post-meta

I make meta box to delete a specific post meta key for the post by AJAX
i make a button when click , delete the key from DB by AJAX

```
add_meta_box('delete_test_key', 'delete test key', 'testdel', 'post');
function testdel(){
?>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="del">delete test key</label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="del" id="del" value="delete"    class="button">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <script>
            jQuery('#del').on('click',function(){
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
                      action : 'ajaxtestdel'
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $this.val('deleted');
        }
        });
            });
    </script>
    <?php
 }
```

and AJAX function

```
function ajaxtestdel(){
global $post;
delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'test');
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxtestdel', 'ajaxtestdel');
```

now the problem is that `delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'test');` not working ,when i put `console.log(data);` in `success` it returned the key value Although the function is `delete_post_meta` not `get_post_meta`, what's the wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `global $post`.

You have to understand that any ajax call, is a **new** http request, that has **nothing** to do with the page that *send* the ajax request.

If you want to pass information from the page that send the request to the page that receive the request, you have to pass the data inside the `data` argument in `jQuery.ajax` function.

Note that the function that print the shortcode receive the current post object as argumnet, so you can make use of it:

```
function testdel( $post ) { // note the $post varaible as argument
  wp_nonce_field('testdel', 'ajaxsecurity'); // is a good practise adding nonces
?>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" id="ajaxtestdel_postid">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="del">delete test key</label></th>
    <td><input type="button" name="del" id="del" value="delete" class="button"></td>
  </tr>
  <script>
  jQuery('#del').on('click', function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var post = jQuery('#ajaxtestdel_postid').val(); // get post id from hidded field
    var nonce = jQuery('input[name="ajaxsecurity"]').val(); // get nonce from hidded field
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: ajax_url, // in backend you should pass the ajax url using this variable
      type: 'POST',
      data: { action : 'ajaxtestdel', postid: post, ajaxsecurity: nonce },
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $this.val('deleted');
      }
    });
  });
 </script>
 <?php
}
```

Now the ajax function:

```
function ajaxtestdel() {
  $postid = isset($_POST['postid']) ? $_POST['postid'] : '';
  $nonce = isset($_POST['ajaxsecurity']) ? $_POST['ajaxsecurity'] : '';
  if ( $postid && $nonce && wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'testdel') ) {
    $status = delete_post_meta($postid, 'test') ? 'Error' : 'Success';
  } else {
     $status = 'Error';
  }
  die($status);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxtestdel', 'ajaxtestdel');
```

Also note that is a good practise separate js from php, so your js should go in a separate js file, enqueued in the post edit page using `admin_enqueue_script` hook and `wp_enqueue_script` function.